# writing html tag into json response

Tags: php, json

CODE:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');

if(mysql_num_rows($result))
{
    while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo json_encode($post);
        echo ',';
    }
}
```

output:

> {"id":"1","layartype":"college","attribution":"Daiict","title":"CEP
>   Daiict","latitude":"23.3400000000","longitude":"34.3334000000"},{"id":"2","layartype":"college","attribution":"Daiict","title":"Lab
>   Daiict","latitude":"23.4500000000","longitude":"34.0960000000"},

this json response in php i m getting in one line..this has actuallly 2 records..i want them to start in a new line....so what do i do?..html doesnot work i suppose.

Comment: But why are you concerned about the layout of JSON data in the first place?

Comment: The correct `Content-Type` for JSON is `application/json`.

Comment: @alex : \n not working...and by writing application/json.. m getting json respone in a dialogue box which i dont want..so i write text/plain..

Comment: @alpesh JSON is meant to be used for data interchange, and you will see that if the browser doesn't know what to do with that mime type.

Comment: @pekka...i am not getting you..

Comment: @pekka...so basically wht do i need to do?

Comment: Obviously, you send multiple JSON responses which turns out an invalid and useless json. See @El Yobo answer and know to echo json_encode string only ONCE, not in a loop.

Comment: @alpesh, sending `text/plain` is wrong - if you're "getting json response in a dialog box" it's because you're handling it wrong on the client side.

Comment: how do i print it on a page itself?...i dont understand wht to do?..suggest something..

Answer (score 2):

This will send the correct content type for JSON and will send all results as a single JSON object (an array of your results).

```
header('Content-type: application/json');

$results = array();
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    while ($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $results[] = $post;
    }
    echo json_encode($results);
}
```

Comment: but this i donot want actually....i have tried this out before...i suggest u to read my question again and answer...

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were sending it for a computer to read.  As scuzzy points out, why would humans want to read JSON?  Doing it this way means that your response is actually JSON; your current script outputs invalid non-JSON, which is readable by neither computers nor humans.

Comment: commedy option: echo str_replace("},{","},\n{",json_encode($results));

Comment: Perhaps if you update your question to say what you want to happen; nobody here has any idea why you want to change the layout of your non-JSON, so we're not sure how to help you.  I don't think you really know what you're trying to do, that's why you're not doing a very good job of explaining it to us :-/

Comment: here i m trying to explain once more..if i write application/json..a dialogue box opens and in tht file i am getting json response...how do i avoid opening a dialogue box?..tell me for this problem

Comment: Include the javascript that you're using to request the JSON in your question, it might help us to try to figure out what you're trying to do.

If you get a dialog box when you request the JSON by typing in that URL in your browser and it asks you where to save it- that's not a problem, that means it's working correctly!  Your browser doesn't know what to do with JSON (your code is meant to do that), so it asks you to save it like any other file.

Comment: ya..xactly same thing happening...that is why i was confused whether it is like an error or what..ok..thanks yobo...